# Symfony/FosUserBundle - Store Roles in DB

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, fosuserbundle

How can I store roles in DB?
I tried this method http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/symfony2-fosuserbundle-role-entities/

USER.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="author")
     */
    public $article;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="full_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles")
     */
    protected $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ....settings...

    /**
     * Returns an ARRAY of Role objects with the default Role object appended.
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array_merge($this->roles->toArray(), array(new Role(parent::ROLE_DEFAULT)));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the true ArrayCollection of Roles.
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getRolesCollection()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * Pass a string, get the desired Role object or null.
     * @param string $role
     * @return Role|null
     */
    public function getRole($role)
    {
        foreach ($this->getRoles() as $roleItem) {
            if ($role == $roleItem->getRole()) {
                return $roleItem;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Pass a string, checks if we have that Role. Same functionality as getRole() except returns a real boolean.
     * @param string $role
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->getRole($role)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a Role OBJECT to the ArrayCollection. Can't type hint due to interface so throws Exception.
     * @throws Exception
     * @param Role $role
     */
    public function addRole($role)
    {
        if (!$role instanceof Role) {
            throw new \Exception("addRole takes a Role object as the parameter");
        }

        if (!$this->hasRole($role->getRole())) {
            $this->roles->add($role);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pass a string, remove the Role object from collection.
     * @param string $role
     */
    public function removeRole($role)
    {
        $roleElement = $this->getRole($role);
        if ($roleElement) {
            $this->roles->removeElement($roleElement);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pass an ARRAY of Role objects and will clear the collection and re-set it with new Roles.
     * Type hinted array due to interface.
     * @param array $roles Of Role objects.
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles)
    {
        $this->roles->clear();
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $this->addRole($role);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Directly set the ArrayCollection of Roles. Type hinted as Collection which is the parent of (Array|Persistent)Collection.
     * @param Collection $role
     */
    public function setRolesCollection(Collection $collection)
    {
        $this->roles = $collection;
    }
}
```

ROLE.php

```
/**
 * Role Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles")
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="role", unique=true, length=70)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * Populate the role field
     * @param string $role ROLE_FOO etc
     */
    public function __construct($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
    }

    /**
     * Return the role field.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Return the role field.
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->role;
    }
}
```

I'm always getting this error.

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
>   Property "roles" in "***\Entity\User" was already
>   declared, but it must be declared only once

Could someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: you are following an out dated article, find the latest article on FosUserBundle and follow that. The bundle supports role out of the box you should not be defining it anywhere.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find latest articles, almost everyone linking to that out dated one.

Comment: Then share your Entity so people can have a look and help

Comment: Done, hope someone will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of everything related to `roles` inside your `User` Entity. Roles are supported by the bundle out of the box.

I just setup the bundle and everything is working fine. This is what my `User` Entity looks like which extends the `BaseUser`

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

Once the bundle was [setup](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#installation), I ran the schema update command.

As you can see the roles `column` is added automatically via the bundle.

[image]

You can play around with bundle using the [command](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/command_line_tools.html#create-a-user) is comes with to create the user.

The documentation of the bundle can be found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html). [Here](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/fosuserbundle-ftw/fos-user-bundle) is another good resource to get you started.

Comment: Yeah I see, but I want special table for all roles. I don't wanna use the security.yml. Because I don't wanna give an access to security.yml.

I'm trying to create CMS, so somehow I need to allow admin create a new role.

Comment: then dont fos user bundle, create a custom one.